# MYSQL combine two GROUP BY result using one command

Tags: mysql

For example, I have fruit come from different country and have different brand(note that the country and brand is independence).

```
+-------+-------+---------+-------+
| name  | stock | Country | brand |
+-------+-------+---------+-------+
| apple |    40 | USA     | Sun   |
| apple |    38 | UK      | Sun   |
| apple |    33 | CN      | Green |
| apple |    29 | UK      | Air   |
| apple |    15 | USA     | Green |
+-------+-------+---------+-------+
```

Normally if we use this command

```
SELECT name, Country, sum(stock)
FROM table
GROUP BY Country
```

It will give the following result

```
+-------+---------+------------+
| name  | Country | sum(stock) |
+-------+---------+------------+
| apple | CN      |         33 |
| apple | UK      |         67 |
| apple | USA     |         55 |
+-------+---------+------------+
```

But what I want is this....

```
+-------+----------+-------+
| name  | category | stock |
+-------+----------+-------+
| apple | USA      |    55 |
| apple | UK       |    67 |
| apple | CN       |    33 |
| apple | Sun      |    78 |
| apple | Green    |    48 |
| apple | Air      |    29 |
+-------+----------+-------+
```

For some result, the command must be one step command, which means only for one command it should able to directly output the above result just one click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing this with a subquery:

```
select name, category, sum(stock)
from (select name, brand as category, stock, 1 as ordering
      from table
      union all
      select name, country, stock, 0 ordering
      from table
     ) t
group by name, category, ordering
order by ordering, name;
```

Note the use of the `ordering` column to ensure that the results appear in the same order as in your desired results.  Also, this will keep two rows in cases where the `brand` and `country` have the same name.  You can remove the `ordering` from the `group by` if you want them combined.

Answer (score 0):

try reading into unions or left join

i think you need to make

```
SELECT name, Country as category, sum(stock)
into #temptable1 FROM table 
GROUP BY Country
```

and

```
SELECT name, brand as category, sum(stock)
into #temptable2 FROM table 
GROUP BY brand
```

then join the two temp tables together
this can be done using stored procedures

or simply union directly without making temp tables

```
SELECT name, Country as category, sum(stock)
into #temptable1 FROM table 
GROUP BY Country
UNION
SELECT name, brand as category, sum(stock)
into #temptable2 FROM table 
GROUP BY brand
```

Comment: You even could remove the `INTO #temptableX` from the first two queries and `UNION` them together: `SELECT name, Country as category, sum(stock) FROM table GROUP BY Country UNION SELECT name, brand as category, sum(stock) FROM table GROUP BY brand`